# Android game catering for all screen sizes - idea

Tags: java, android, screen-size

I have been developing a game for Android and I had an idea for catering for the different screen sizes, and I would like feedback on whether the idea is a good one, and how it can be improved, or if it shall be scrapped.

What I have is a 2d size scrolling game, where it is locked it landscape mode. Because screen sizes vary, the width of the screen (usually height, but it is in landscape so I shall refer to it as width) changes. This causes all sorts of problems for me with moving the background because it is basically two identical pictures scrolling, and as one leaves the screen the other begins to replace it, so I must catch the image when it has just left the screen, so it can be reset and ready to scroll again. This means it must reach an int value every time, else it will not be caught and both images would scroll off screen.

My idea, which I have briefly tested is as follows. Truncate the screen size to the nearest 100px. Add 100 to this value and have that as the width for the background images. Then divide this value by 100 and use this as the rate of px per frame it moves. This would mean that the background would move at a similar rate dependent upon screen size (set frame rate of 25FPS). It would move faster on larger screens and slower of smaller screens, but would move at the same speed relative (1% per second or whatever).

Is this idea flawed? I have tested it vaguely on a few screen sizes but the emulator is verry laggy, and I only have a couple of devices to test it on (I am only 18 so I cannot get my hands on many!).

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it on a large sized screen?  I guess the only thing I see as an issue is the speed-up on larger screens or slow down on smaller screens would impact game-play.

Comment: @nycynik I have tried it with large screens. The speed relative to the size of the screen is the same (eg. 10% of the screen per second). It works perfectly well, the only problem is that my actual images are really bad, so look awful on large screens!